# Re-render the component on same routing path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, render, react-router-v4

I am new in React Router.

I have a menu bar to switch the page using React Router 4.

I found that the page will not trigger re-render if I clicked the menu item that is current path.

(e.g. current path is /person and click the menu item that will switch to /person)

I have the following React router.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path={"/home"} component={Home} />
    <Route path={"/person"} component={Person} />
    <Route path={"/contact"} component={Contact} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
</Switch>
```

How do I trigger re-render the component if clicked the current route?

Thanks

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be triggering complete remount in such cases

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a menu item, if you don't change any `props` or `state` of its page components, this component will NOT re-render. So, you should write a function which does 2 things: `loadData()` and `Push()`. Then, call it when you click on the menu item.

Comment: Do you mean there is no config in React Route to force re-render the component?